# compare multiple columns in a row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question from HackerRank :
Sample Input:

```
select * from triangle;
A   B   C
20  20  23
20  20  20
20  21  22
13  14  30
```

Sample Output should be :

```
Isosceles
Equilateral
Scalene
Not a triangle (as sum of two sides not greater than the third side)
```

I have tried it with Case ,But it becomes messy as I have added lots of conditions there

```
select 
case
when ((A+B) > C ) or ((B+C)>A) or ((C+A)>B)then  
 case when (A=B) and (B=C) then 'equilateral'
 when (A=B ) or (B=C) or (C=A) then 'isosceles'
when (A!=B) and (B!=C) and (C!=A) then 'scalene'

end
else 'not triangle'
end Name from triangle;
```

I am aware of decode ,But decode will not work here ,I guess.
Is there any better way this code can be build instead of using CASE?

Answer (score 5):

```
select a, b, c,
       case when a + b < c or a + c < b or b + c < a then 'Not a triangle'
            when a = b and b = c then 'Equilateral'
            when a = b or a = c or b = c then 'Isosceles'
            else 'Scalene'
       end description
  from triangle
```

Output:

```
         A          B          C DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
        20         20         23 Isosceles
        20         20         20 Equilateral
        20         21         22 Scalene
        13         14         30 Not a triangle
```

Comment: That's not quite correct - if a = 10 and b = 10 and c = 20, you haven't got a triangle, you have a straight line. Your initial case condition needs to have less-than-or-equal operatiors, not just less-than.

Comment: @Boneist - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) says: _the sum of the lengths of any two sides must be greater than **or equal** to the length of the remaining side._ ;-)

Comment: true, but I guess it depends on whether you're using Euclidian geometry or not: [In Euclidean geometry any three points, **when non-collinear**, determine a unique triangle...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle) *{;-) It's up to the OP to decide if the triangle with angles (0, 0, 180) is actually a triangle or not in their case! *{;-)

Comment: Hi Ponder Stibbons ! Thanks for the answer . Is there any other way to develop the same code instead of using CASE ?

Comment: Hi Joe. `Case when` is optimal here. The only other solution which comes into my mind is to write a function with 3 input parameters (lengths) and returning string and then use this function when selecting. In function write conditions similiar to these above in separate `if`s.
I think `decode` is bad idea here. I would use `case` for sure.